# How to persist using Realm an instance from a class which comes from a dependency library

Tags: swift, realm

I am both new to **Realm** and **Swift** and I am having trouble persisting an object from a Class that I can't edit so that it will inherit Realm "Object".

Problem Description:

1) I have a project, let's call it **MyProject**

2) I have imported a Paid Framework, let's call it **PaidFramework**

3) This Framework has several classes that I want to persist, but let's call one of them "PaidClass", which have some inheritance, but they're all `NSObject` subclasses at final

4) I am getting a list of "paidClass" instances, that I want to persist using Realm

Unfortunately, I cannot add multiple inheritance, using for example, an extension for every PaidClass I need to persist.

After that, I am hesitating to recreate every PaidClass I need to persist (they are about 10) because I would have to create MyPaidClass instances from PaidClass (adds time to the execution) and a lot of code that is duplicate.

I really hope someone has made a better, easier, concrete implementation solving this problem.

Comment: Do you need to be able to query those instances based on all of their properties or do you simply want to be able to persist them?

Comment: I would like to add them, for example, as List variables in some Classes I will create, and then both retrieve all of them or asking Realm queries on these.

Comment: In that case there's no easy way to handle this other than creating your own wrapper class around those. Or of course if the framework is open source, you could try to modifying the framework. If you only wanted to persist those classes, but wouldn't need to filter queries/create relations based on them, you could have simply encoded them to `Data` and store them as `Data` in Realm.